# Transparent background picture and the color of certain points

Tags: gnuplot

Basically I have a picture which is a collection of complicated shapes with its own axis and different colours and a data set of points which I can plot on top of it, that works fine, see minimized code example. I am using fortran to generate a gnuplot command file and run gnuplot.

```
plot "Random.png" binary filetype=png with rgbimage axis x2y2, "xydata1.dat" using 1:2 with points axis x1y1
```

My problems are that the picture makes it hard to see the points on top. Due to the shapes being a lot of different colours it is impossible to pick a colour for the points which is clearly visible on all shapes.

So could the picture be put in the background at say 50% transparency, without making it transparent in another program?

And is it possible to get the colour of the background on the locations of the points back so that the shape they are in can be determined automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rgbalpha` plotting style and given an explicit transparency value:

```
plot "Random.png" binary filetype=png using 1:2:3:(127) with rgbalpha axis x2y2\,
     "xydata1.dat" using 1:2 with points axis x1y1
```

The transparency value must be between `0` (completely transparent) and `255` (fully opaque).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I didn't know that the using 1:2:3:(127) part could be used with a picture instead of an array. Do you have a clue if the second part of my question can be done?

Comment: No, that cannot be done, because gnuplot only knows about the data it is currently plotting and you cannot access the data from a second file. So you must preprocess your data by a different program. Or, if this is feasible, you can generate a third column inside your fortran program, which contains these informations.

Comment: Thanks again. The information is not there yet and I was wondering if gnuplot could help me acquire that information, so the third column in fortran wouldn't help unfortunately. But now I know gnuplot won't solve it so I know I have to look elsewhere.